# JsonIgnoreProperties not working with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

Currently, the Spring Boot sample application is created normally. In the request, if there are any unknown fields coming, then we need to throw an error.

For this the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)` annotation is being used. However, when I am accessing the URL, it is not working.

Please find code snippet as follows:

```java
    @RestController @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false) public class
    UserController {
        private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

        private final UserRepository userRepository;

        private final UserDAL userDAL;

        public UserController(UserRepository userRepository, UserDAL userDAL){
            this.userRepository = userRepository;       
            this.userDAL = userDAL;     
        }

        @RequestMapping(
            value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
        )   
        public User addNewUsers(@RequestBody @Valid User user) 
            throws JsonProcessingException {        


            LOG.info("Saving user.");

            CardInfo cardInfo = new CardInfo();
            cardInfo.setCardId("12345678901");      
            user.setCardInfo(cardInfo);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(cardInfo);
            user.setCardInfo1(jsonString);  
            userDAL.getAllUsers();      

            return userRepository.save(user);   
        }
```

Please find sample Pom as follows:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.journaldev.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-mongodb</name>
<description>Spring Boot MongoDB Example</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have at least 3 options:

1. Put `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on a class you deserialize, and not in Spring controller.

   - However, I see that the class you want to deserialize is `com.journaldev.bootifulmongodb.model.User` so, most probably, you can't modify it.
2. Configure your [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance:

```java
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
```

3. [Customize Spring Boot's Jackson Object Mapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) - by setting a correct environment property:

   spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true

For further information, please refer to [section 76.3 of Spring Boot's reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html).

Comment: Option#3 works. However, option#1 was not giving expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, option 3 is what works for me. #1 does not work.